# Change of orientation performance issue - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

when orientation changes in android, native android call the destroy method and total new layout is to be made as far as I know. But I think codenameone doesn't do that which is a great thing. But when I checked the cn1 app in devices while changing from portrait to landscape a blank screen is seen for a while and then the orientation changes.

```
My Problem is that when I have many more components displayed in a form,
the blank screen appears for a longer duration and sometime it hangs. Does it 
happen as I don't use Orientation listener methods etc or is there anything I 
can do to solve this issue?
```

Comment: It behaves like that on my device too.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on my device and it worked fine for the latest build on my Android 6 device. There was the rotation animation from Android where the screen rotated into its new place.

I'm guessing the rendering of your screen is so slow that Android takes too long to draw it and ends up drawing a black screen instead so it can proceed with the animation.

I can't benchmark an application remotely but I suggest [going over the performance of your app](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---improve-application-performance-or-track-down-performance-issues.html) and making sure it is truly optimized.